# Format text of UILocalNotification.alertBody

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am looking for a way how to format text of `alertBody` of `UILocalNotification`. I noticed that for example mail app sets first line from Subject and second and third lines are preview of email body. If subject is longer than 1 line, it is truncated. This works correctly with dynamic font, so no matter what text size is set in accessibility.
I tried to do achieve same result, but with no success.

What I tried

1. Truncate string to specific length
2. Getting string size with `sizeWithAttributes` while using `preferedFontForTextStyle`

All these solutions partially work, but for some text size/device will fail

What I am looking for is an approach to get lock screen's notification font name, size, kerning or any other parameters neccessary to be able to properly set `UILocalNotification.alertBody` as only 1 line of text on any iOS device with any text size accessibility setting.

I am aware that these properties may be different for different iOS version, but iOS8 is enough for me.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for approving and sorry about the negative response: while it is not what you may have hoped for, it seems that local & remote notifications are in the same wrapper, and that the OS does not give you a hook at display time. It is sort of understandable, since for an app to format a notification would mean for that app to be running, and of course you can receive them while not launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Let the OS do the layout

The closest you are going to get to is a guess.
You can use

```
"\n"
```

to enforce a carriage return, but you won't know *for sure* when to use it.

There is no iOS support to let you tell, ahead of time, what is the screen size or orientation your notification will arrive.

**You are up against the banner:**

Banners do not display `localNotification.alertTitle`

[image: 2 notification banners, portrait and landscape]

**Then up against the clock, so to speak:**

You create notifications ahead of time. The fact that they are local is no reason to know what the future will hold: for all you know, you may be scheduling 1 month from now, and the user may have updated the OS, causing new fonts or layout constraints to apply.

In other words, the answer to this question is:
*You need to work for Apple Computer and get a local callback prior the notification is displayed, which is, as of date, not an option.*.

[image: Notification Center]

---

**Conclusion**

Use **short** `alertTitle`, **short** `alertBody`, possibly sprinkled here and there with `\n` to force new lines.

```
// Use '\n' to force newline
localNotification.alertBody = "Alert fired.\nWas set for ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Apples mail applications first line is the `alertTitle` property, recently introduced >= iOS 8.2 *2015-03-09* [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertTitle).

> Use this property to provide a short description of the reason for the alert. You may specify a string with the text you want to display or you may specify a string to use as a lookup key in your app’s Localizable.strings file. The default value of this property is nil.
>
> Title strings should be short, usually only a couple of words describing the reason for the notification. Apple Watch displays the title string as part of the short look notification interface, which has limited space.

Per your second note, all notification's `alertBody` strings are truncated, depending on it's length. The notification only displays so many characters to complement the `UILocalNotification` specific height. However, no matter what size, if you pull down on the notification, it will display the remaining characters provided there are any, just like Apples mail application. You *can* shorten your `alertBody` using whatever [method that works for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW22), but as far as formatting it in terms of `UIAppearance` protocols, there is no approved method by Apple

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `alertTitle` is not first line of mail's notification body. It replaces name of the app text if notification is displayed in notification center, but you cannot see it on lock screen. Also, for the second note - I know how to truncate the `alertBody`, the question is how to get the length to fit exactly one line on lock screen, because different devices have different size and users can set different size of text